# How Can I Get List Of Ended Events From Google Calendar API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

Here is the code:

```
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });

const meetingsResponse = await calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 1,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
     });
```

Output: ?

Do someone know where is the problem?

Comment: Please show us the output you have got so far.

Comment: Hi noctrune, i tried doing timeMax to current Time Still its not working i am not able to get latest ended events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **timeMax** to the current **datetime** to get a list of ended events.
If you really want to get only 1 result (latest ended event) you can retain **maxResults** to 1

**timeMax**

- Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by.
- This will the the maximum date time that the event's start time should have configured.

**timeMin**

- Lower bound (exclusive) for an event's end time to filter by
- This will the the minimum date time that the event's end time should have configured.

**For Example:**

timeMax = 2020-12-23T11:00:00Z (datetime now)

Event 1 start time = 2020-12-22T08:00:00Z

Event 2 start time = 2020-12-23T14:00:00Z

- [events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?hl=en) should return event 1 (ended event) since event 1's start time is less than the timeMax.

> In your code, when you use timeMin to filter the dates, you are saying that the minimum datetime that the event's end time should be now. Hence, events.list() will return the events that has end time greater than the timeMin(now) which are events that are not yet ended.

**Sample:**

[image]

**timeMax = 2020-12-23T11:00:00Z**

**Response (deleted some unnecessary information):**

```
{
  ....

 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "summary": "ended event 1",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-22T20:30:00+08:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-22T21:00:00+08:00"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "summary": "ended event 2",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-20T16:00:00+08:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-20T16:30:00+08:00"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "summary": "ended event 3",
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-21T11:00:00+08:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-12-21T11:30:00+08:00"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Ron
I tried doing this
const meetingsResponse = await calendar.events.list({
                calendarId: 'primary',
                timeMax: (new Date()).toISOString(),
                maxResults: 1,
                singleEvents: true,
                orderBy: 'updated',
            });
Strill its not working...

Comment: Can you specify what error did you encounter? You may also want to try it first here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?hl=en

Comment: I'm not getting any error but I'm getting Wrong Json Output for my API

Comment: Sure Will try it here

Comment: HI Ron, Setting maxTime to Current Date Time is retruning my first event on Calendar

Comment: sorry about that, yes the only order option when filtering `singleEvents` is either by **start time** or by **update time** which are both in ascending order.

Comment: One workaround I could think of is that you may need to set timeMin and timeMax to get a list of range from a period of time. Example `timeMax = now timeMin = 1 week earlier/1 day earlier (depends on how often you expect events)`. This will return a list of events which are arranged by created date. You need to check the end time of each events manually

Comment: Okay Ron, Thanks for the Answer will implement it in my Code. Will update if i face any issues..
Thanks for Helping !!!!
Really Appreiciate